# "Computational method" or "computation method"?

Tags: word-choice

I proposed a method for computing the entropy of an image.  In this case, can I refer to the method as a "computational method" or "computation method"?

What is the difference between "computational method" and "computation method"?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

In the first case

> computational method

describes the method, that you are working out the results by computation. Another method of obtaining the results could be

> empirical method

which means that it is based on observations. In the second case

> computation method

describes the computation itself, given the first case. That method could be, say statistical analysis.

Comment: In my case, which is better?  According to your answer, it seems that both are ok?

Comment: My answer does not say which is better: it says they mean different things. The answer is in two parts: the first part decribes the use of "computational" and the second part describes the use of "computation".

Answer (score 0):

If the emphasis is on a particular type of "method", then using "computational" as a modifier is grammatically appropriate.